# What does the phrase "Elven for AI" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase Elven for "AI" in the following text (not available online):

Grimes has a fascination with AI. So much that the “Æ” in her son’s name is Elven for “AI”.

The text is about a woman who has created a lullaby with the help of AI. Please note that her son's name is X Æ A-Xii.

I know that the word Elven means "relating to an elf", but am confused about its relevance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Elven" means "the language of the elves".  Since elves are fictional, their language is also fictional.  The best known elven language are the languages invented by Tolkien for his books *The Hobbit* and *Lord of the Rings*:  Quenya and Sindarin.

Presumably this means that Æ means AI in the language of the elves.

(Except in Sindarin, artificial intelligence would be something like *hannas tam*, or HT?)

Comment: Didn't Tolkien use "Elvish" rather than "Elven" to refer to the languages? I also don't grasp how Æ could relate to AI; the Æ ligature does feature prominently in Elvish tongues (and in the real life languages they are based on) but it doesn't have any meaning by itself and neither the orthography nor pronunciation seem to connect. But this may be a defect on the part of the original author, not of your answer.

Comment: I've seen Ae  (not Æ) used in elvish as an exclaimation, rather like "Ohh!" or perhaps "Aii!"  It is possible that Grimes just used a Sindarin dictionary that translated Ae! as Ai! and thought it meant A.I.  That is, it's just like someone getting the Chinese characters for "chicken noodles" tattooed on their arm.  A failure to use a dictionary properly.